# How to know which image is set on ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView that can have either of two images ( say image 1 & image 2, stored in drawable). If ImageView contains image1 I want click on that ImageView to be disabled and if image 2 is being displayed, on click image should change to image1 & click is disabled on ImageView.
I am unable to find way to know which image is currently being displayed on ImageView.

This is my code

```
ImageView select = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.select); 
select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
} 
});
```

Comment: Can you share what have you done so far?

Comment: ImageView select = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.select);
select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  });

Comment: in listener how to know which image is currently being displayed in imageview (given id as select).

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest approach to that would be to keep track of this state separate from the UI, and have the UI reflect the state you're interested in. I.e., if it's an Enabled/Disabled representation, keep track of whether this is enabled in a boolean with a proper setter method, and have that method update the UI. This may also be a good application for [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).

Comment: may be an example would have been more helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is for button :

```
final Button whichLane = (Button) reportDialog.findViewById(R.id.which_side_icon);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        whichLane.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (whichLane.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.other_side).getConstantState()) ) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "text", 10).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider creating your own View that extends [CompoundButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html).
The checked state would be an image and the non-checked state the other.

Answer (score 0):

Set id to imageviews like this select.setId(imageArray[i]) [for ref see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325071/how-to-identified-which-image-is-clicked-in-imageview/24325201#24325201)
and do onclick action what you want in that.

```
public static int[] imageArray = {
         R.drawable.image1,
         R.drawable.image2

         };
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageArray[i]);
    select.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    select.setId(imageArray[i]);
    select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         if(v.getId()==R.drawable.image1){
                   //here you set image2 to select 
             } 
         else{
                  //here you set image1 to select
         }
    } } );
```

Comment: i know it is too long to reply but it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Integer`  and change it's value when you change your image.
For example use a

```
public Integer num;
```

when you set image1 on the view, change num's value to 1.
and in the `onClickListener` method check whether num is 1 or not.
i.e.

```
if (num == 1)
```

change to image 2 else change to image 1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `tag` in imageview and check for the image accordingly. Then when you change the image, again set the `tag` for the image view. An example :-

Here I am showcasing the example for 8 images. I have first set image named `p1` from layout file and set the image view tag as `1`. Then when the user taps on the image, I check the `imageview` tag name. And change the image accordingly.

```
   imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String tagId = imageView.getTag().toString();
            switch (tagId) {
                case "1":
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p2));
                    imageView.setTag("2");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p3));
                    imageView.setTag("3");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p4));
                    imageView.setTag("4");
                    break;
                case "4":
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p5));
                    imageView.setTag("5");
                    break;
                case "5":
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p6));
                    imageView.setTag("6");
                    break;
                case "6":
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p7));
                    imageView.setTag("7");
                    break;
                case "7":
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p8));
                    imageView.setTag("8");
                    break;

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem, and i can tell you what I did. I found this most simplest

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView iv;
Button btn;
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(i==0)
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.baloon); //baloon -> first image
                i=1;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sky); //sky -> second image
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

NOTE:- Here in xml, I used sky as the initial image of the image view, which is important otherwise our image will not change on first click.