# How to identified which image is clicked in imageview

Tags: android

```
ImageView imageAd =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.HomeimageViewAd);
```

ad4 and ad5 are changing on regular interval in imageAd (i.e imageview) and i want to find which image is click

//Image resource in an array

```
private int[] imageArray = {
         R.drawable.ad4,
         R.drawable.ad5
     };

Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageArray[i]);
imageAd.setImageBitmap(bmp);
imageAd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   // here i want to identified which image is clicked  
} } );
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you did there... What is ad4 and ad5, and what is imageAd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set id to imageviews like this
imageView.setId(imageArray[i]);

Then check with id.
The entire code will be like as follows

```
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageArray[i]);
        imageAd.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        imageAd.setId(imageArray[i]);
        imageAd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if(v.getId()==R.drawable.ad4){

                 } 
        } } );
```