# how can i get the source of my imageview

Tags: android

Iam just making an app which has to set a random source to image view

but I need to know the new -randomly selected- source
for the image view

is there is a method to get the resource directly?

I tried making a tag like :

```
imageView2.setTag(R.id.pic2)
int newpic = getResource(imageView2);
```

using this method :

```
public int getResource (ImageView iv){
    int id = iv.getTag();
    return id;
}
```

but it doesn't give me the new random resource

can I have some help?

Comment: *"but it doesn't give me the new random resource"*

Do you mean it gives you the older one or does it give you nothing?

Comment: `into id = iv.getTag();` ? into? You mean int? Both would not compile.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325071/how-to-identified-which-image-is-clicked-in-imageview

Comment: kamran
it gives me the older one

Comment: greenapps
it is typing error 
i mean int